# Only last row is printing

Tags: arrays, go, httpresponse

this is my go function

```
func logInFirst(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    type Resp struct {
        Result  []map[string]interface{} `json:"Result,omitempty"`
        Result1 []map[string]interface{} `json:"Result1,omitempty"`
        Result2 []map[string]interface{} `json:"Result2,omitempty"`
        Status  string                   `json:"Status"`
    }
    type AxleUser struct {
        ShopID      string `json:"ShopID"`
        VehicleType string `json:"VehicleType"`
    }

    var Response Resp
    Response.Status = "failed"
    Result := make(map[string]interface{})
    Result1 := make(map[string]interface{})
    Result2 := make(map[string]interface{})
    //db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:chikkIbuddI57@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/b2b")
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "awsgobumpr:gobumpr123@tcp(briaxpgbmpr.cx4twoxoumct.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com)/b2b_optimization")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    rnd := render.New()
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
    defer req.Body.Close()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    // Unmarshal the request body
    var msg AxleUser
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &msg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    //fmt.Println(msg)
    // get shop id from emp table using mobile number and password
    brandrows, branderr := db.Query("SELECT DISTINCT brand,model FROM admin_vehicle_table_new WHERE type=?", msg.VehicleType)
    if branderr != nil {
        panic(branderr.Error())
    }
    brandcolumns, branderr := brandrows.Columns()
    if branderr != nil {
        panic(branderr.Error())
    }

    brandcount := len(brandcolumns)
    brandValues := make([]string, brandcount)
    brandScanArgs := make([]interface{}, brandcount)
    for i := range brandValues {
        brandScanArgs[i] = &brandValues[i]
    }
    for brandrows.Next() {
        branderr := brandrows.Scan(brandScanArgs...)
        //fmt.Println(branderr)
        if branderr != nil {
            panic(branderr.Error())
        }
        for i, v := range brandValues {
            Result[brandcolumns[i]] = v
        }
        Response.Result = append(Response.Result, Result)
    }
    servicerows, serviceerr := db.Query("SELECT DISTINCT b2b_service_type FROM b2b_service_type WHERE b2b_vehicle_type=? and b2b_flag=0 and b2b_shop_id=0 UNION SELECT b2b_service_type FROM b2b_service_type WHERE b2b_vehicle_type=? and b2b_flag=0 and b2b_shop_id=?", msg.VehicleType, msg.VehicleType, msg.ShopID)
    if serviceerr != nil {
        panic(serviceerr.Error())
    }
    servicecolumns, serviceerr := servicerows.Columns()
    if serviceerr != nil {
        panic(serviceerr.Error())
    }

    servicecount := len(servicecolumns)
    serviceValues := make([]string, servicecount)
    serviceScanArgs := make([]interface{}, servicecount)
    for i := range serviceValues {
        serviceScanArgs[i] = &serviceValues[i]
    }
    for servicerows.Next() {
        serviceerr := servicerows.Scan(serviceScanArgs...)
        if serviceerr != nil {
            panic(serviceerr.Error())
        }
        for i, v := range serviceValues {
            Result1[servicecolumns[i]] = v
        }
        Response.Result1 = append(Response.Result1, Result1)
    }

    repairrows, repairerr := db.Query("SELECT DISTINCT b2b_repair_decription FROM b2b_repair_decription WHERE b2b_vehicle_type=? and b2b_shop_id=0 UNION SELECT b2b_repair_decription FROM b2b_repair_decription WHERE b2b_vehicle_type=? and b2b_shop_id=?", msg.VehicleType, msg.VehicleType, msg.ShopID)
    if repairerr != nil {
        panic(repairerr.Error())
    }
    repaircolumns, repairerr := repairrows.Columns()
    if repairerr != nil {
        panic(repairerr.Error())
    }

    repaircount := len(repaircolumns)
    repairValues := make([]string, repaircount)
    repairScanArgs := make([]interface{}, repaircount)
    for i := range repairValues {
        repairScanArgs[i] = &repairValues[i]
    }
    for repairrows.Next() {
        repairerr := repairrows.Scan(repairScanArgs...)
        if repairerr != nil {
            panic(repairerr.Error())
        }
        for i, v := range repairValues {
            Result2[repaircolumns[i]] = v
        }
        Response.Result2 = append(Response.Result2, Result2)
    }

    Response.Status = "success"
    res.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    rnd.JSON(res, http.StatusOK, Response)
}
```

My Desrired output is a json string like this

```
{
  "Result": [
      {
         "brand": "Hero Honda",
         "model": "Passion Pro"
      },
      {
         "brand": "Yamaha",
         "model": "120"
      },...
  ]
"Result1":[
     { 
       "service_type" : "repairs",
     },
     { 
       "service_type" : "general service",
     },...
  ]
  "Result2":[
     {
       "b2b_repair_decription": "Tire Replacement"
     },
     {
       "b2b_repair_decription": "Electric work"
     },...
  ]
}
```

but the output which i got contains the same row instead of all the rows like 
this,

```
{
  "Result": [
      {
         "brand": "Yamaha",
         "model": "120"
      },
      {
         "brand": "Yamaha",
         "model": "120"
      },...
  ]
"Result1":[
     { 
       "service_type" : "general service",
     },
     { 
       "service_type" : "general service",
     },...
  ]
  "Result2":[
     {
       "b2b_repair_decription": "Electric work"
     },
     {
       "b2b_repair_decription": "Electric work"
     },...
  ]
}
```

i tried appending in the loop , but it dint work. i even tried defining the Result, Result1, Result2 as array of interfaces

can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: You're allocating `Result`s only once at the start of your loops, then in each iteration of loop you fill that one value and append it to the result slice, each iteration overwrites the contents of the `Result` values and therefore every appended value will hold the contents from the last iteration. You should allocate each `Result := make(map[...` in their respective loops so that every append appends its own unique value.

Comment: .. something like this https://play.golang.org/p/CNYnx6t6-8B

Comment: yuhoo... IT WORKS! Thank you @mkopriva